# MYSQL - Query for getting distinct sender_id and receiver id and richiesta_id

Tags: mysql

I've this table "messages" results:

[image: table messages result from first query]

I've tried with:

```
SELECT idutente, richiesta_id
FROM (
  SELECT sender_id, richiesta_id
  FROM messages
  UNION
  SELECT receiver_id, richiesta_id
  FROM messages
) AS DistinctCodes (idutente)
WHERE idutente IS NOT NULL;
```

but is not work or not correct. How can i get from table you see 
a table as:

```
|    richiesta_id     |                users                |
|---------------------|-------------------------------------|
| 55                  | 2, 3, 4                             |
| other richiesta_id  | other users list separated by comma |
```

Comment: Try `) AS DistinctCodes (idutente,richiesta_id)`, or simply `) AS DistinctCodes`.

Comment: "Is not work or not correct" doesn't help us much. Always on SO you should say 1) what result you expected 2) what result you got 3) how it different from what you expect. Never just say "it doesn't work"

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a combination of "GROUP BY" and "GROUP_CONCAT" to archive this.

```
SELECT DistinctCodes.richiesta_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DistinctCodes.uid ORDER BY DistinctCodes.uid ASC)
FROM (
  SELECT sender_id AS uid, richiesta_id
  FROM messages
  UNION
  SELECT receiver_id AS uid, richiesta_id
  FROM messages
) AS DistinctCodes
GROUP BY DistinctCodes.richiesta_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it:

```
SELECT sender_id as idutente, richiesta_id
FROM messages
WHERE sender_id IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT receiver_id, richiesta_id
FROM messages
WHERE receiver_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: How this answer will return comma separated list?

Comment: I tried but it's not result expected.. check the this [link](http://www.testcolan.it/chatcarpack/rest_api/screen.png)

Comment: @CristianCapannini, Please tag your DBMS product and version.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai will must return sender and receiver id comma separated but distinct each one... thanks

Comment: @CristianCapannini, Are you using MySQL? If yes, then what is your version?

Comment: I'm using mysql of Aruba... and the version is (I think) Software version: 5.7.26-29-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 29, Revision 11ad961

Comment: @AnkitBajpal at the time the answer was written, the question didn't clearly specify that requirement